# How can I infer widths from a flattened Bundle?

Tags: chisel

I am trying to wire a `BlackBox` to an arbitrary `Bundle`, but width inference does not seem to work with the fromBits function.  The following compiles fine:

```
class testBundle extends Bundle {
  val io1 = Bool(INPUT)
  val io2 = UInt(INPUT,10)
}

class testBox extends BlackBox {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val in = Bits(INPUT) # Width inference works fine here
    val out = Bits(OUTPUT,(new testBundle).getWidth) # But it doesn't work here!
  }
}

class test extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val in = new testBundle
    val out = (new testBundle).flip()
  }
  val testbox = Module(new testBox)
  testbox.io.in := io.in.toBits
  io.out := io.out.fromBits(testbox.io.out)
}
```

But if I remove the `(new testBundle).getWidth` argument, Chisel cannot infer the width of the output port and errors out.  How can I get `testBox` to connect to arbitrary bundles?

Answer (score 0):

For now I am solving this by passing in the bundle as an argument to the BlackBox:

```
class testBox(b:Bundle) extends BlackBox {
  val w = b.getWidth
  val io = new Bundle {
    val in = Bits(INPUT,w)
    val out = Bits(OUTPUT,w)
  }
}

class test extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val in = new testBundle
    val out = (new testBundle).flip()
  }
  val testbox = Module(new testBox(io.in))
  testbox.io.in := io.in.toBits
  io.out := io.out.fromBits(testbox.io.out)
}
```

I'd welcome a cleaner solution, though.